# bootstrap - Make Columns heights that of the width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a input box which takes up 6 grid units. In height, it takes up 21.981px as in figure 1

I want to be able to have it be a square like in figure 2. How can achieve this

[image]

[image]

```
 <form class ="form-inline">
                <div class="row">
                 <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                        <input id="p1a" type='text'
                               style='border: solid black 1px;'
                               onfocus='this.blur()'
                                readonly='true'
                                size='1'
                               value='&#x2753;' onclick='tristate_Marks(this)' />
                    </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS for this:

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.square {
  width: 100%;
  padding: calc(50% - 21px) 0;
  line-height: 21px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="square" value="test" />
```

Comment: Getting there. but it apears there is an extra 21px in the height, so the padding isent taking into account the height of the element itself. Is there a way to do something like 100% -21px??..
also this does not centre the text

Comment: I edited the answer. Don't know what you are using it for, but with an input field, this is the closest you will get

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Working now. Im using it for a custom checkbox with 3 states

Answer (score 0):

Although Thomas answer is correct and worked, i changed my approach to use js

```
window.onload  = function () {

    var width = $("#p1a").width();
    console.log(width)
    $("#p1a").height(width);
}
```

This does not resize the box on resize,but i do not need this functionality